# fetching embedded documents on search criteria of another embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have a collection HostelTbl which has many documents one of the document is like

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"),
    "Name": "Hostel-MGL-02",
     ...
    "RoomsDetails": [
     {
       "RoomId": "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb",
       "FloorNumber": "1",
       "RoomNumber": "101",
        ...
     },
     {
       "RoomId": "050c65ab-355e-9bec-00a0-2999e75bcdc4",
       "FloorNumber": "1",
       "RoomNumber": "104",
       ...
     },
     {
       "RoomId": "f197c635-a6fb-b4d6-9cf5-ed53177edd47",
       "FloorNumber": "2",
       "RoomNumber": "109",
       ...
     },
     ...
     {
       ...
     }
    ],
   "AllotmentsDetails": [
   {
      "AllotmentId": "5eb05e1d-2690-afad-747a-ef29450ae3f3",
      "StudentId": ObjectId("5ab8d5d4ff24ae120400085e"),
      "RoomId": "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb",
      "FromDate": ISODate("2018-06-12T22:00:00.0Z"),
      "ToDate": ISODate("2018-07-04T22:00:00.0Z"),
      ... 
     },
     {
      "AllotmentId": "40d73d84-0f94-48d8-823c-2255fd2ae0ed",
      "StudentId": ObjectId("5ab8d5bcff24ae120400085d"),
      "RoomId": "050c65ab-355e-9bec-00a0-2999e75bcdc4",
      "FromDate": ISODate("2018-01-21T22:00:00.0Z"),
      "ToDate": ISODate("2018-02-06T22:00:00.0Z"),
      ...
       },
       {
      "AllotmentId": "40d73564-0f94-48d8-823c-2255fd2440428",
      "StudentId": ObjectId("5ab8d5bc4624ae1204000855),
      "RoomId": "f197c635-a6fb-b4d6-9cf5-ed53177edd47",
      "FromDate": ISODate("2018-03-21T22:00:00.0Z"),
      "ToDate": ISODate("2018-05-04T22:00:00.0Z"),
      ...
       } 
     ] 
  }
```

I have two embedded documents inside one documents. One is storing rooms information and another storing rooms allotments to a student information.
Now I want to fetch those available rooms from RoomsDetails if their allotments detail's "ToDate" field contains the dates in past from today inside AllotmentsDetails Embedded document. Like in the above case the rooms with ids
"050c65ab-355e-9bec-00a0-2999e75bcdc4", f197c635-a6fb-b4d6-9cf5-ed53177edd47 contains ToDate dates in the past inside AllotmentsDetails embedded documents. It should fetch those two rooms only.

I am not able to find such queries. Please help!!!

I am trying to tweak the below lines of code

```
public function fetchAllAvailableRooms() 
{
   $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate(array(
             array(
                   '$match' => array(
                                "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)
                                )
                  ),
             array(
                  '$project' => array(
                  'RoomsDetails' => array(
                  '$filter' => array(
                  'input' => '$AllotmentsDetails',
                  'as' => 'allot',
                  'cond' => array(
                  '$lt' => array('$$allot.FromDate', $this->Today)
                   )
                  )
                 ),
               'Name' => 1        
                )
              )
            ))->toArray();

    return $cursor;
   }
```

Comment: It really helps to show and expected result from the data you actually supply, and most importantly that the data you supply can actually produce that result. It also helps to show that you have at least tried something, even if it does not work. Are you really talking about a "single document" here? Or does this detail span several documents and need to be brought together? Producing the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes it much clearer, as does  your code attempt at least indicate the possible direction.

Comment: You have not answered any of the questions raised in the comment other than supplying your code attempt. Can you please address the questions and points raised by ["editing your question"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50675205/edit) as there needs to be a reproducible result here and I see none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operators for that.

- [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) - for `AllotmentsDetails` transformation into final list
  of the room ids
- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) - for `RoomsDetails` filtering by the
  final list of the room ids

Example:

```
public function fetchAllAvailableRooms() 
{
    $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate([
        ['$match' => ["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)]],
        [
            '$addFields' => [
                'filteredIds' => [
                    '$map' => [
                        'input' => '$AllotmentsDetails',
                        'as' => 'item',
                        'in' => [
                            '$cond' => [
                                ['$lt' => ['$$item.ToDate', $this->Today]],
                                '$$item.RoomId',
                                false
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$project' => [
                'RoomsDetails' => [
                    '$filter' => [
                        'input' => '$RoomsDetails',
                        'as' => 'item',
                        'cond' => ['$in' => ['$$item.RoomId', '$filteredIds']]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])->toArray();

    return $cursor;
} 

/* Result example
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae69fb4d2ccda0e70005551"),
    "RoomsDetails" : [ 
        {
            "RoomId" : "050c65ab-355e-9bec-00a0-2999e75bcdc4",
            "FloorNumber" : "1",
            "RoomNumber" : "104"
        }, 
        {
            "RoomId" : "f197c635-a6fb-b4d6-9cf5-ed53177edd47",
            "FloorNumber" : "2",
            "RoomNumber" : "109"
        }
    ]
}
*/
```

**P.S. PHP code is not tested, so i'm not 100% sure if it is working.**

**P.P.S. The final solution is strongly depends on the details of your project.**